# Duplicate tags to remove

Tags: support, tagging

We talked with Alenanno in chat (and see also the discussion [here](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/38)) and we agreed that some tags cover intersecting sets of questions. Here they are:

- *english-to-russian* and *translation*: we want to keep *translation*, because it is more general and because, if I understand correctly, this site is not for russian-to-english translation.
- *swearing* and *mat*: we want to keep *swearing*
- *terms* and *terminology*: we want to keep *terminology*, nobody's using *terms*
- Also, I think that tag *inclination* was created to denote *declension*, and it would be nice to keep the latter and remove the former.

Is it possible to remove *english-to-russian*, *mat* and *terms*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merged and created synonyms:

- [mat](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mat) -> [swearing](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swearing)
- [terms](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terms) -> [terminology](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology)

It doesn't look like [inclination](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inclination) exists anymore.

I haven't touched [translation](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) since there's still more discussion to be done about that.

Answer (score 0):

I support 2--4, however not 1: a translation may be from/to other languages than English, and at some point there may be some Russian-French, or Russian-German specialists and discussions here. I'd try to keep the tags as specific as possible, without overdoing it. I would also keep `translation`, because the OP may offer a term in several languages and ask what that would be in Russian.

Comment: I'd keep only Language X to Russian translations, provided the original expression was explained enough and there was research effort. By the way, tags shouldn't be too specific, otherwise you have 1000 instead of 700 more appropriate ones.

Comment: @texnic What if we keep only the translation tag for questions like "How do you say X in Russian", but we also add tags such as "English", or "German", or "Spanish" specifically for questions that involve other languages? They would cover not only the cases of translating English-specific words into Russian (such as "How do you write West-End: "Уэст-Энд" or "Вест-Энд"), but also all kind of special loanwords from these languages, similarity in syntax, and so on. I suggest it because most of the current translations are not exactly "Eng-to-Rus", but "official_site_language-to-Rus".

Comment: @Olga I like your suggestion.

Comment: Is there some way to ask others about their opinion?

Comment: @Olga Well, they see this correspondence. For now, we do not have a set rules yet. I think, your other post about better organization of the tags is very timely, let's just slowly progress. As long as no one objects, everything is fine. We just should not move too fast, give people at least a couple of days to read and respond to important messages (which by default are all posts on the meta, I would say).

Comment: @Olga You might want to open a separate meta question to get some eyes on your suggestion. Most people probably won't be looking in the comments here and expecting to find something to offer input on.