# What should our tags be? What should they be translated to?

Tags: discussion, tags

After having [being notified about the ability to use tags in Russian](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/221/71), let's start proposing the translation for the tags. I'll provide the current tags we have and we'll all start to decide the translations so we can set up the synonyms later.

Obviously you can comment in separate answers or using comments.

We'll be using this question also to select the tags and get rid of some duplicates or tags that shouldn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Successfully merged tags list

> Disclaimer: The tag syntax doesn't currently work for Russian text. [I filed a bug report](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/229/71), so ignore it for now. Thank you.

Legend: **Old tag** (synonym) > **New tag** (master)

---

[aspect](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aspect) > [вид](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4)
[cases](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cases) > [падежи](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8)
[culture](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/culture) > [культура](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0)
[etymology](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology) > [этимология](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%8f)
[gender](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender) > [род](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4)
[genitive](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genitive) > [родительный-падеж](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b6)
[grammar](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) > [грамматика](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0)
[history](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) > [история](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f)
[language-history](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-history) > [история-языка](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0)
[linguistics](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linguistics) > [лингвистика](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0)
[literature](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literature) > [литература](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0)
[mathematics](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics) > [математика](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0)
[phonetics](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phonetics) > [фонетика](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0)
[phonology](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phonology) > [фонология](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%8f)
[plurals](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plurals) > [множественное-число](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be)
[poetry](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry) > [поэзия](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%8d%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%8f)
[prepositions](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prepositions) > [предлоги](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8)
[punctuation](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punctuation) > [пунктуация](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f)
[syntax](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax) > [синтаксис](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81)
[translation](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) > [перевод](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4)
[verbs](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verbs) > [глаголы](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b)
[vocabulary](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary) > [лексикон](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd)

Answer (score 2):

This is the list of tags taken from the site. Some Russian tags already existed and those I knew I transferred as translations of existing tags. Help match the remaining ones (end of the list).

Notes:

- Don't insert new tags: propose them first separately in another answer, so we can discuss it. Before inserting a translation, propose that in another answer as well, so we keep everything organized.
- Tags have a maximum of 25 characters, so we cannot have tags longer than that. Read more about tags [in the Privileges page](https://russian.stackexchange.com/privileges/create-tags).
- Some tags must be plural, others must stay singular. For example "meaning" makes sense as a singular word, "cases" as a plural one. If you have concerns about this, post here: [Tags should be plurals (with some caveats)](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/37/71).

Thank you for your cooperation! :D

**See the other answer for the created tags.**

Comment: We should also make a final decision on whether we use singular or plural for tags.  I believe, we discussed this before and decided that singular is a better option.

Comment: @AleksG It depends on the tag. Sometimes it's better to use plural, other times singular. Other languages sites have generally chosen plural, like on [EL&U](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/72/should-we-prefer-singular-or-plural-in-tags).

Comment: @AleksG For example, for tags like "verbs, synonyms, pronouns" I'd say it's better plural. For tags like "meaning, pronunciation, terminology", singular is better. By the way, thank you for the additional translations! :)

Comment: @AleksG Where was that decided by the way?

Comment: I take my previous comment back.  It was "plural" that we decided on.  [Here's the discussion](http://meta.russian.stackexchange.com/questions/37/tags-should-be-plurals-with-a-few-caveats) (or rather the corresponding post).

Comment: @AleksG Thanks for the link. I agree with it but it's not "decided"... In any case, I think it works for Russian as well, so we can safely adopt it. :) If you see tags that can be fixed, please do it! :)

Comment: I agree with plural for most of the tags. But I think we should consider using singular for lexical categories (`глагол`,`имя-прилагательное`).

Comment: @defaultlocale Other sites use "verbs", "глагол" looks a bit odd, even if the question is about a single verb.

Comment: @AleksG I corrected согласныя to согласные. Let's hope that Quassnoi had time to appreciate the joke.

Comment: Alenanno, @Olga I have a question concerning composite (multiple word) tags. In English it's common to use a hypen to connect words, so "word-choice" does not look strange. "Выбор-слова" on the contrary very much does. Shouldn't we rather use an underscore in Russian?

Comment: Alenanno, @Olga: Does it make sense to put a link to this post to FAQ, so that people know where to see a list of approved tags?

Comment: @texnic I don't see the need... Why do you think that would help? Tags change (slowly but they do), so it's not like this list is definitive.

Comment: Well, I am not an admin and I do not appear here too often I admit. But I sometimes find information not very easy to find. I'd like to have one place which everyone should be aware of instead of dozens of posts, which are hard to maintain and find.

Comment: @texnic Ok but what I mean is that, no other site does it I think, so maybe it's not needed. I'm not particularly against your proposal, I just don't see a compelling pro-argument. :P Where would you write it and how, for example?

Comment: Alenanno, @texnic: If we introduce tag synonyms, they will be appearing as suggestions when one wants to tag a post, wouldn't they? So, one doesn't necessary need to have a look at the list of approved tags to ask a question?

Comment: @Olga, Alenanno: It's not about synonyms, it's about a full list of tags. When I tag a question, I should first start typing it to see a hint. If something does not come to my mind, I will not see the synonym either. For the sake of having nicer tagged questions, I would provide a list of tags, since we already have it (here). I'd have it added to FAQ in a new section "How to ask a nice (good) question?" I believe it's covered somewhere else at SE, but how many of our users will read it there?

Comment: @texnic Why don't you create a Meta question about it? Like, in the Question you ask "what are the tags?" and in the answer you'll start listing the tags, we'll help you. Then we will link it from the FAQ. I was actually thinking of doing something like this: [Linguistics Community FAQ](http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/344/111) :) There we could also put a Russian version of the FAQ (so we don't clutter the actual FAQ, and we'd link it from there).

Comment: Alenanno (@Olga): so you suggest creating another question on tags? I agree, though I thought this question of yours is exactly that. But true, it becomes rather long by now :) Let's keep the discussion here and make another question with the actual tags list. Everyone agrees?

Comment: Concerning Linguistics Community FAQ: http://meta.russian.stackexchange.com/a/253/47

Answer (score -2):

### Let's have English tags as primary

I propose to consider the English language as the main language of the tags on our site. Let's make Russian synonym tags that redirect to the English ones. I don't want to translate tag wikis, so let's keep the English as well.

My reasons are:

1. the most of the site is in English, so it would be coherent to have tags in English as well;
2. the English tags are already there, with wikis. Let's not redo the work.

Comment: Point 1 does not really subsists. As we have seen on French SE, what matters is localization. Making important Meta questions both in Russian and English will help, etc... Point 2, uhm... well, nobody is forcing you to translate all of the tag wikis or that you should be the only one, you shouldn't feel obliged to do it. Besides, no-one says we need to translate them all at once. Little by little is fine, as with everything else. The tags in Russian will make this site more appealing to Russian speakers and learners, so I say: *let's go for it*.

Comment: @Alenanno ... and the tags in English will make it more appealing for the rest of the world =) I remember that nobody was eager to create wikis for tags in the beginning, I don't think that there will be more people willing to do it once again. And as you can see, people tend to ask questions in English, not in Russian.

Comment: That's now, but we can think in perspective... If everything goes right, more people will ask stuff in Russian too. As you can see, some questions are being asked in Russian already.