# The "[tag:tag-name]" syntax does not work with Russian text

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag

I was trying to use the syntax for writing tags such as [tag](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag), but it doesn't work with other input methods, such as Russian: [тэг](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d1%8d%d0%b3)

I'm tagging this as a bug since I figure it's not the desired behavior. Can we add support for that? Also considering the recent enabling of Russian tags.

Comment: Yes, seems like an oversight by me. I expect we're using an overly restrictive regex or similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed for posts, comments and the chat system; it will be deployed in the next build.

Comment: I wrongly thought it wasn't fixed because the post preview still doesn't recognize the notation for non-alphabetical tags. Will it be fixed for previews?

Comment: @ento I'll have to look