# Should tags be in Russian or English?

Tags: discussion, tagging

This site is about Russian language, and it's appropriate to use Russian tags.

Should I use tags Russian or English for a question?
What is the policy for tagging?

It seems reasonable to use English tags when the question is in English, and vice versa – Russian tags if the question is in Russian. Such tags should be made synonims of each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current way works that you can write whatever language you want for tags, but once you submit the question, it will change all tags to Russian. See also [What should our tags be? What should they be translated to?](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226/what-should-our-tags-be-what-should-they-be-translated-to)

This way also learners can enter tags (in English) but the site will have them in Russian. If you wish to change this you can post a [feature-request](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) on Meta asking for specific changes (just asking "change it" won't work).

Some tags are not "set" yet, we're finishing the job. For example, in your last question you used both *phonetics* and *фонетика*. I've mapped the first one to the second one and the English one has disappeared. Now if someone types phonetics, the system will use фонетика.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's perfectly fine. I asked this question because I saw `phonetics` tag but there was no `фонетика` tag, and I saw questions tagged with the former. So I felt a bit confused. Looking through tag synonyms I can see English tags are mapped to Russian ones. I couldn't create the synonym myself and therefore I decided to use both in the hope someone, you, make them synonyms.

Comment: I would also add that by convention those few SE.L&U sites I had visited do translate their tags, but for English-speaker it is easy to see what to use, once they are synonymized.