# винительный падеж tag -- Should all tags be associated with their English translations?

Tags: discussion

I don't have enough reputation to propose a tag synonym, but I was wondering, for a lot of tags (e.g. грамматика) it also suggests the English translation.

However, a lot of tags aren't linked/associated with their English translation. For example, "винительный падеж" -- I think this is a useful tag, but it has not been used very often.

I don't know why it hasn't been used very often, but I imagine the fact that it isn't associated with "accusative case", so someone typing "acc" in the **Tags** bar is not likely to find it, which probably prevents it from being used more often.

This is related, but I believe different to [this question](https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/304/7239) -- specifically, I would just like to address the fact that there seem to be tags on this site which learners can not enter in English, and therefore are perhaps as a result used less often than they would be otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created an synonym tag. I guess we should create them for all the rest of the cases.